# Displacement modifier texture not matching color texture

Tags: texturing, modifiers

I'm trying out the displacement modifier for bump mapping, and I'm stuck with a problem. The displacement texture doesn't matches my color texture, and I can't find a way to resize it too.
Here's how it is looking like: [image]

I'm having troubles resizing it too. I've tried resizing the UV Map, but it only changes the color texture: [image]

Technically I could resize them with the mapping controls, but they use different units so I would have to tinker it by eye.

[image]

So how do I get the displacement texture to match the color texture position and size? They were generated on CrazyBump, by the way, so they're not different sizes or anything.

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles?

Comment: @gandalf3 The screen shot shows cycles...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the displacement modifier to use the UV map:
[image]

To change the size, simply scale the UV map up or down, by going into the UV editor and hitting <kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: Dang, I shouldn't have missed that one. It worked perfectly, thanks a lot!